# Safely turning off RTS for Linux installation

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just put in a secondary SSD on my Windows machine, and I tried installing Linux on it. However, Linux told me that the machine has RTS (Rapid Storage Technology) enabled, and I need to disable it. I found a setting in BIOS that I can switch from RAID (which I think is the same as RTS) to AHCI. However, I got a warning that this may ruin my Windows installation. Is there any way to install Linux safely on my second SSD?
Also, can I turn RTS back on just for the SSD with Windows, after I install Linux
Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure rebooting and changing BIOS every time is going to make you suffer.  I would convert your Windows to use non-RST AHCI and then install Linux after on the second SSD.  (https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci for how to disable RST and reenable AHCI, though I haven't done this in ages so you use this at your own risk - also, not affiliated with that site)

Comment: I agree with Ward: when you use 2 systems in a dual boot you need to only use settings both support (that would be ACHI in this case). You can switch windows to ACHI w/o reinstalling

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank you for the info and the link!

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Harvested from my comments and turned into an answer:

I'm pretty sure that trying to remember to constantly switch back and forth is going to kill your brain and your patience.

It's better to convert your Windows to AHCI mode and then install Linux afterwards.  This is not a Windows support site, though, so I'm not going to do more than give you a link to [a guide I found via Google to do the conversion](https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci).

It is better to use settings that both support, so the AHCI setup for Windows is what you're going to want to do, then install Linux and you'll save yourself a massive headache.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think turning off RTS will affect the performance of Windows though? It seems like RTS is a niche thing, useful only for people who have both an SSD and a HDD, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user56202 I've never found an improvement in dual boot with Intel RST personally, but I've only ever had HDD or SSD, not both.  SSDs are fast enough you don't really *need* RST in my opinion unless you're really working with large data, mutlidisks, etc. but that doesn't work in Linux anyways so